# Exporting SmoothHistogram plot data

Tags: export, histograms

My program produces a large data set, which is distributed by some unknown function. I've used `SmoothHistogram` to visualise it crudely as a probability distribution function, but now I want to export the plot data from `SmoothHistogram` - is there a way for me to retrieve just the line `SmoothHistogram` plots, so I can analyse it in an external program?

Comment: Try `First@Cases[SmoothHistogram[something ...], Line[a___] :> a, Infinity]`! This is the data now use `Export` on this data and for help with the possible export file format check the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods:

1. Extract the data directly from the `SmoothHistogram` plot:

   ```
   r = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
   plot = SmoothHistogram[r]
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   pts1 = Join @@ Cases[plot, Line[p__] :> p, ∞]
   ```

   > ```
   > {{-4.10173, 0.}, {-4.10173, 0.}, {-4.09273, 0.000372864}, ... }
   > ```
2. Use regular `HistogramList` with the subsequent smoothing

   ```
   pts2 = Transpose@{(Most[#] + Rest[#])/2, 
     GaussianFilter[#2, 12 {3, 1}, Padding -> 0.0]} & @@ 
       HistogramList[r, {-3.5, 3.5, 0.02}, "PDF"];
   ```

   Here `12*3 = 36` is the radius of Gaussian smoothing and `12*1 = 12` is the standard deviation in units `0.02`.

Verification:

```
ListLinePlot[{pts1, pts2}]
```

[image]

Then you can `Export` `pts1` or `pts2`.